# Endpoint configuration for AspNetCore HealthCheck UI at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, health-monitoring, health-check

I can't find a solution to change endpoint configuration for [Asp.net Core HealthCheck UI](https://github.com/xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#HealthCheckUI) at runtime.
It can be configured in appsettings.json, or in Startup, but I need to control endpoints at runtime. (e.g. based on integration events)
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Using *DatabaseStorage*, changes in table *Configurations* is reflected in UI. So implementing simple CRUD features on this table solve the problem.